# D3js text not reading from database data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on this project and momentally I need  to display only one number which is return from database from my backend.

This is my code:

```
var data2 = d3.json("/Events/CountEmployees/").then(function (data) {
    d3.select("#data")
        .selectAll("p")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('p')
        .style("color", "red")
        .text(data => data.Count1);
   // console.log( data);
})
```

When I execute the console.log(data) command it actually reads my wanted data but I don't get the problem is with the text attribute in D3js.

This is the result I get from it:
[image]

Now what I want is to display that data from count1 which is "6" as a text on my page but I am stuck and I can't find any solution. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What type of element are you selecting with an id of `#data` and does it have any child 'p' elements already? If you inspect the page do you see added elements? If you log data.Count1 in you text function do you see what you expect? You need a bit more info to identify a problem.

Comment: No actually. I can't access directly the row of data. Instead I can log the whole "table" that I retrieve from database by using console.log(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

Added `<h4 id="rData"> </h4>` on my html side,
and this script on my .js file.

```
var data2 = d3.json("/Index/MyData/").then(function (data) {
    const test = data.map(d => d.Number);
    $('#rData').text(test);
})
```

Since I am retrieving data from database, I had to use a d3 function to get those data from my controller function (MyData) which return these data.
Leaving this here in case someone else needs this some time in the future.